# System Verilog, order of execution?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In system Verilog if I have:

```
module my_module (
        input logic clk,
        input logic rst,
        output logic A,
        output logic B
    ;(
    logic A = 1'b0;
    logic B = 1'b0;
```

Then A and B will be connected to 0 at the same time.
But what about a situation where I have something like this:

```
module my_module (
    input logic clk,
    input logic rst,
    output logic A,
    output logic B
;(
logic and_out, or_out;
always_ff @(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin
    if (rst == 1'b1) begin
        A <= 1'b0;
        B <= 1'b1;
    end
    else begin
        A <= or_out;
        B <= and_out;
    end
end
always_comb begin
    and_out = A & B;
    or_out = A | B;
end
endmodule
```

How will be the order between always_ff and always_comb? will they get excuted at same time?

Comment: *Then A and B will be connected to 0 at the same time.*
$$\,$$
No. They are just zero. A and B don't exist in "time". They are just a specification that says "anything connected to this is 0".
$$\,$$
This isn't a procedure, it's a definition!

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry I didn't get that, I learnt that A and B are wires and when I do =0 then the wires are grounded (no electricity) or low voltage

Comment: replace "when" with "if" in that sentence, and you get exactly the right meaning: this means these wires are hardwired to 0, as if they were soldered there, in the circuit. If you think about what you do in verilog as builiding a schematic: it's really just writing "GND" everywhere that A and B are connected to. There's no "simultaneous" when there's no time!

Comment: what about my main question? will always_ff run first of always_comb or they both run in same time? @MarcusMüller

Comment: The order of execution of procedural blocks is not specified, in general. The important issue is the difference between how blocking and non-blocking assignments are treated. That is well documented on the web.

Comment: is that really a question? `always_comb` triggers at time 0, and it blockingly sets `and_out`/`or_out` based on the values of A and B at time 0; by definition of what the non-blocking assignment `<=`, *can* the result take effect before time 0?

Comment: why at time 0? so you are saying it excites first all the time? that doesn't make sense to me I mean I was expecting always_ff to run first then always_comb as it was written later... (in case the clock was up)

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, `A` and `B are static variables that get initialized before the existence of simulation time, and never assigned again. They are essentially  the same as a constant.

In your second example, all `always` blocks execute as concurrent processes starting at time 0. But a simulator actually puts all `always` and `initial` blocks in a queue to begin execution at time 0 in an unspecified order. Also note that an `always_comb` is equivalent to

```
always begin
 and_out = A & B;
 or_out = A | B;
 @(A or B);
end
```

This guarantees the block gets executed at least one at time 0, so in case somehow A and B get updated first, the outputs will get updated.